# netbeans logging tutorial

Tags: java, netbeans, logging

hi i'm working with a netbeans project, that they gave me to work on, and i need to check if the connection to the database (postgres) are working well, and i notice that there are lines in the code like

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getNivel.class);
```

then

```
if (user != null) {
            log.debug("Usuario identificado: " + user.getIdUsuario() + "obteniendo su cuadro de mandos");
```

but i don't know how to see if the connection is actually working, because i can't find the log file. so i searched the internet and i found this page
[link](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/doc-files/logging.html)

but i don't really understand what i should do to see those messages. Can anybody help me?

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile

Comment: Assuming you're using lo4j you should take a look at the doc http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which logging library you use, but I presume you use the standard java logging api (java.util.logging package) ...

You dont probably see it because you are using DEBUG level of logging and your project is set to print WARNING and above I believe. So if you what to quickly see whats going on, either change temporarily the code to:

```
if (user != null) {
        log.severe("Usuario identificado: " + user.getIdUsuario() + "obteniendo su cuadro de mandos");
```

OR create logging.properties file in the root of you project, where you will enable logging on DEBUG level for the class or package for which you want to see the logs:

```
com.mycompany.mypackgepath.myclass.level=DEBUG
```

Note, that there might be already such a file in your project. Also you can add more handlers in order to print the log output to a file as well as to netbeans console

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/Library/Logs/xd%g-%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 10485760
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 2
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.encoding = UTF8
```

You might want to check this tutorial for example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143

Btw. the logger should be `private` and `final` ;)